# Measuring width of contour at given angle in OpenCv

Tags: python, opencv, contour

Given a contour in OpenCV, I can extract the width and height by using `cv2.boundingRect(contour)`. This returns the width and height of a bounding rectangle, as illustrated by the left figure.

Given an angle, is it possible to extract the width/height of a rotated bounding rectangle, as illustrated in the right figure?

[image: Contour illustration]

I am trying to measure the length of moving objects, but I need to measure the length in the movement direction, which may sometimes be up to 45 degrees from the horizontal line.

I know there is a way of getting *a* rotated bounding rectangle, using `cv2.minAreaRect` and `cv2.boxPoints`, but the rotation I need will not always match the minimum area rectangle, so I need to be able to specify the angle somehow.

I only need the rotated width and height values, I don't really need the rotated contour, if that makes it easier.

Comment: rotate the object and apply the bounding again `getRotationMatrix2D`

Comment: Why not. Support you have an angle, then you can make two orthogonality lines. Calculate the distance between pts and each line, then calc `max_dist - min_dict`, you will get width and height.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As my comment: `Why not. Support you have an angle, then you can make two orthogonality lines. Calculate the distance between pts and each line, then calc max_dist - min_dict, you will get width and height.`

`My mother language is Chinese`, and not I'm good at English writing. So I just turn it into code:

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
# 2017.12.13 22:50:16 CST
# 2017.12.14 00:13:41 CST
import numpy as np

def calcPointsWH(pts, theta=0):
    # 计算离散点在特定角度的长宽
    # Measuring width of points at given angle
    th = theta * np.pi /180
    e = np.array([[np.cos(th), np.sin(th)]]).T
    es = np.array([
    [np.cos(th), np.sin(th)],
    [np.sin(th), np.cos(th)],
    ]).T
    dists = np.dot(pts,es)
    wh = dists.max(axis=0) - dists.min(axis=0)
    print("==> theta: {}\n{}".format(theta, wh))
```

---

Give this diamond for testing:

[image]

```
pts = np.array([[100, 200],[200,  26],[300, 200],[200, 373]], np.int32)
for theta in range(0,91, 30):
    calcPointsWH(pts, theta)


==> theta: 0
[ 200.  347.]
==> theta: 30
[ 173.60254038  300.51081511]
==> theta: 60
[ 300.51081511  173.60254038]
==> theta: 90
[ 347.  200.]
```

Now it's `2017.12.14 00:20:55 CST`, goodnight.

Comment: Thank you, this seems to do exactly what I wanted. I didn't intend for you to actually do all the work, but I'm very grateful for it! :)

Answer (score 1):

use

```
cv2.minAreaRect(cnt)
```

Here you can find [***here***](https://docs.opencv.org/3.1.0/dd/d49/tutorial_py_contour_features.html) complete example and explanation.

Edit: minAreaRect is actually what you need, what's the problem in taking width and height from an oriented rectangle?

Comment: Thanks, but unless I'm thinking about this the wrong way, the minimum enclosing rectangle will not always be "facing" in the direction of movement. For example in the case of @Silencer's diamond: the minimum enclosing rectangle will be constant, but the direction of movement will not.

Comment: This sound weird, can you add some image example of what's happening in your code? (maybe a snippet too)

Comment: Consider this 100x100 square, moving at an angle of 45 degrees: https://i.imgur.com/PvHyHL6.png cv2.minAreaRect will return a rectangle that looks exactly like the square, won't it? That would give me a width of 100, and a height of 100. But since the square is moving at 45 degrees, I want the width at 45 degrees, which is approximately 141. Therefore, minAreaRect won't work (unless we rotate the rectangle, which could be a solution, but then I need help doing the actual rotation :) )

Comment: This is not related at all to what you asked. That square has a 0 degree angle, no matter which the direction is. The diamond of Silencer ha a 45° with a +kPI° depending exclusively of your reference system. And the width of a 100x100 pixel square rotated by 45° is still 100.

Comment: Sorry, I obviously wasn't clear enough in my question. As I tried to illustrate in the figure in the question, the shapes will never actually be rotated, but the direction of movement may change. And I need the width in the movement direction. Silencer's solution seems to calculate just that.

Comment: So just measure the length of the line from the center of the object to the center of the object at the new position. You don't even need to know the angle